# asp .net checkbox inside gridview checked

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I have a main 'Products' table and a 'Products_Recommended' table. I want the users to be able to select several products from a GridView using checkboxes and then insert those Product IDs (prodid) into the Products_Recommended table in such a way that a main Product ID is entered (coming from query string) and potentially several recommended ProdIDs get entered. So far so good.
But I need to be able to show the checkboxes to be checked if there were already prodids in the Products_Recommended table previously. 
The code below show a 'sqldatasource1' which gets the data from the Products_Recommended table based on query string. I just don't know how the checkboxes can get checked because the GridView has a different sqldatasource binding it.
Thanks!
Meengla

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="Products" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="prodid"
    DataSourceID="alldata" EnableModelValidation="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ProductSelector" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="itemnumber" HeaderText="Item Number" SortExpression="itemnumber" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="itemtitle" HeaderText="itemtitle" SortExpression="itemtitle" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="SelectedProducts" runat="server" Text="Recommend" OnClick="SelectedProducts_Click" />
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="lblProdSelected" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
</p>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="alldata" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbconnection %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Products">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="14" Name="itemid" QueryStringField="itemid"
            Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbconnection %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM dbo.products_recommended WHERE prodid = @itemid)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="14" Name="itemid" QueryStringField="itemid"
            Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `RowDataBound` event, and in the method [find the checkbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) and set its `Checked` value.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Products" OnRowDataBound="GridViewRowEventHandler">

void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    var ProductSelector = e.Row.FindControl("ProductSelector") as CheckBox;
    ProductSelector.Checked = true;
  }
}
```

You can use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select.aspx) method of DataSource to retrieve the data you need

Comment: Okay. Let me try your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, but the Gridview itself is bound to sqldatasource with id 'alldata' while the checkboxes need to be populated or not based on the values from the sqldatasource with id of 'SqlDataSource1'. So your solution will not work?

Comment: @Meengla You can use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select.aspx) method of DataSource to retrieve the data you need

Comment: but how? I have been stuck half a day so if easy to point out then please do so.

Comment: You should read the documentation about this method, and you didn't provide any info about rules for the checking/unchecking your checkboxes

Comment: Okay, I will look up documentation. Sorry if I did not explain above. Basically, if the 'products_recommended' table has a 'prodid' which matches the query in the SQLDatasource with id of 'Sqldatasource1' then the checkboxes should check. thanks!

Comment: @meengla Then you have to select the `products_recommended` table from your datasource or move this query into `alldata` field

Comment: I already have the 'sqldatasource1' querying the right table; unless I make some kind of special query which selects all from the 'products' table and then selects -only- matching ones from the products_recommended table I don't see how this will work. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. I ended up storing the product id values in the same database tables as an array and then dynamically checked checkboxes. Works just fine. Not ideal but not too bad either. Thanks for your help.